# Consulta usuario mysql cumpla dos columnas de requisito

Tags: mysql, sql

he estado tratando de filtrar **username** de la tabla **usadas**, que cumplan dos condiciones.

1. que en la columna **groupname** sea del tipo **2hPausada**
2. que el valor de la columna **used** sea entre 02:00:00 y 03:00:00

   MariaDB [radius]> SELECT * FROM usadas;

[image: Tabla usadas]

He usado:

```
SELECT * FROM usadas WHERE used BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '03:00:00';
```

[image: filtro1]

El cual me filtra la columna used en el rango especificado.

pero me gustaria que filtrara y mostrara ademas el **groupname** *2hPausada* pero no he logrado hacerlo, si alguien podria guiarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM usadas 
WHERE used BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '03:00:00' and groupname = "2hPausada"
```

En la **claúsula where** debes poner las condiciones que deseas usando el **operador lógico and**.

Comment: Gracias me funciono perfecto, muchas gracias Dios te bendiga.

Comment: @AbdiasRiveraBautista gracias a ti, un placer